# How to get posts by custom taxonomy in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, I am trying to get posts from a custom post type 'color', custom taxonomy 'color-name', using the following:

Notes: I have a custom post type, Color, with custom posts that are titled things like, 'Coral', 'Peony'. I also have a custom taxonomy, color-name. Through a hook on saving a color post, categories in that custom taxonomy get created. Then, the custom post type Color, can be tagged with other related colors.

```
$slug = str_replace(" ", "_", $page_title);
$slug = strtolower($slug);

//Slug is - 'coral', 'peony', etc.

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'color',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'tax_query' => array( array (
                       'taxonomy' => 'color-name',
                       'field' => 'slug',
                       'terms' => $slug
                                   ) )
);
$myposts = query_posts( $args );
```

I've tried many variations of this after Googling, and nothing is working - I either get all posts, or no posts. Here's another version of args I've tried: (results in no posts):

```
  $args = array('color-name' => $page_title,
                'post_type' => 'color',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'caller_get_posts'=> 1
               );
```

I've wrestled with this before and gave up and just made a custom sql call. Does anyone know definitively how to get this working through WordPress functions?

Comment: How are you getting your terms. It seems that is your problem. Also, **NEVER** use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query and in most cases outright fails in pagination. Also, `caller_get_posts` is longtime depreciated, was replaced with `ignore_sticky_posts`

Comment: You mean this piece? 'terms' => $slug? $slug is a string, like "peony".

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I believe `$slug` is your problem. Are you sure the result from `$slug` is a string and not an array. Please [edit] your question and add your code for `$slug`. I want to have a look at that

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do, in words: List all posts tagged 'blue' under a custom taxonomy called color-name, that are also in a custom post type 'color'

Comment: OK, that make a bit of sense. The part that doesn't, blue, is that a post tag or a term inside color-name

Comment: It's a term inside color-name. I just updated my question with more backstory.

Comment: Your output from `$slug` is wrong. Your string should look like this `'coral, peony, etc, etc'`

Comment: Even when I write it out by hand, that doesn't work, though. 'coral' doesn't work -

Comment: Add this in your template to check what slugs are returned. `$terms = get_terms(NAME_OF_TAXONOMY);
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo "<li>" . $term->slug . "</li>";
        
     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }`

Comment: Ah! Maybe it was the slug! I'm not sure what I missed the first time I answered you here, though now I've got a query that's working. Adding to my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Actually - the answer below is what I needed, marked as accepted, with terms written out. Now off to figure out the dynamic terms on my own, now that hand-written is working. :) Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, just change your query accordingly to what I've said in my first comment.

Comment: I'll be posting an answer later to help you out there if you don't come right

Comment: For some reason it works, dynamically, just the way I had it. I'm not sure what happened, but if it works it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts()`. For example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'color',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'color-name',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $slug
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Do something.
    }
} else {
    // No posts found.
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Ref:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query